# Unable to open Mozilla Firefox

Tags: permissions, firefox

```
pinank@pinank-NE56R:~$ firefox

(process:14941): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:14941): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(firefox:14941): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(firefox:14941): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(firefox:14941): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
Could not create gnome accelerators directory `/home/pinank/.gnome2/accels': Permission denied
```

Hello,
I am new to Linux and I am unable to open my Firefox browser, it seems there are some permission issues. Can anyone please guide me? The above is the terminal error that is shown in my laptop.

Thank You.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `ls -ld /home/pinank/.gnome/accels`. That shows us the owner and permission flags of the mentioned directory. After you showed them to us, we can correct them. Please notify me with a comment containing "@ByteCommander" after you updated the question. Thanks and welcome on AskUbuntu!

Comment: pinank@pinank-NE56R:~$ ls -ld /home/pinank/.gnome/accels.
ls: cannot access /home/pinank/.gnome/accels.: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry, typo. It has to be: `ls -ld /home/pinank/.gnome2/accels`

Comment: ls: cannot access /home/pinank/.gnome2/accels: Permission denied

Comment: Then: `sudo ls -ld /home/pinank/.gnome2/accels`

Comment: ls: cannot access /home/pinank/.gnome2/accels: No such file or directory

Comment: total 0
 is after using sudo ls -l /home/pinank/.gnome2/

Comment: Show me a `sudo ls -l /home/pinank/.gnome2/`, please.

Answer (score 1):

You probably messed up either the owner or the permissions of your directory

```
/home/pinank/.gnome2/accels
```

This can be fixed and reset to the correct values:

- permissions: `drwx------` or `700` (equal permissions, but different notation)
  It means that it's a directory (`d`) and that only the owning user has full access (read/write/execute) while neither the owning group nor other users may do anything with it (not even enter and display contents).
- owner user: your user (`pinank`)
- owner group: your group (`pinank`)

You correct the owner with the command:

```
sudo chown pinank:pinank /home/pinank/.gnome2/accels
```

You correct the permissions after that with the command:

```
chmod 700 /home/pinank/.gnome2/accels
```